# Is there a utility to tidy VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, tidy

I'm wanting a tool to tidy VBScript code. I'm looking for something to do the same job as perltidy for Perl, or astyle for C++ and Java code.

I've looked, but failed to find anything here or via Google. Open Source software would be preferred.

Can anyone point me at one please?

Comment: Did you ever find one or build one? I'm looking for one too.

Comment: Not one that met my needs - but my work has moved away from VBS into Powershell so i stopped looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tried , but maybe this:

http://www.sourceformat.com/vbscript-beautifier.htm

Comment: You should mention that this link does not link to a free or open source solution / editor

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what text editor you are using.

If you know how to use Vim you can open the file with it and this command:

```
=G
```

Comment: That does indentation yes, but I'm looking for rather more complete tidying of code - lining up assignments on the = signs and the like, which is why I gave astyle and perltidy as examples.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very happy with an application I purchased online called VBSedit.  Don't know the guy or anything, but it is a good editor.  I was previously using Notepad++ FWIW